# How can I get node creation date?

Tags: theming, 8, nodes, datetime

How can I get node creation date and convert it to custom format in my theme, I tried to make some operations on node date in "MyTheme.theme" file and in `preprocess_node` section.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Code for getting node created date.

```
$date = $variables['node']->getCreatedTime();
  // Here you can use drupal's format_date() function, or some custom PHP date formatting.
  $variables['date'] = \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format($date, '$format');// enter date format in $format.
```

Comment: Just see this article on Drupal.org's feeds: http://knackforge.com/blog/rajamohamed/formatting-way-date-time-displayed-drupal-8

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your answer. If you want to use a custom date format, you have to declare it this way:

```
$variables['date'] = \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format($date, 'custom', '$format'); // Where $format is a PHP date string like 'M Y'
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.