# How to print the 'authored on' date in the template (twig file)?

Tags: theming, nodes

I looked at the solutions provided for similar questions but they all post the date the article was updated on.

This is what I use:
`<h2>{{ post.getCreatedTime|date("Y") }}</h2>`

I just want to print the year.

Answer (score 1):

The variable name is not 'post', it should be 'node' and the filter is `format_date`:

`{{ node.getCreatedTime|format_date('date_format_machine_name') }}`

Comment: That still prints the date when the node was updated.

Comment: It gets the creation timestamp. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Entity%21Node.php/function/Node%3A%3AgetCreatedTime/8.4.x

Comment: It's also noted in the template doc page: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21templates%21node.html.twig/8.4.x

Comment: when I use this `node.published_at is empty ? "" : node.published_at|date("m/d/Y")`  or this `node.getCreatedTime is empty ? "" : node.getCreatedTime|date("m/d/Y") ` it prints nothing. So I guess the published_at date is null. not sure where I can go from here

Comment: What is `published_at`? I thought you were asking about Authored On, which is the core date field on a node for indicating created time. Counter to that, the created timestamp should never be empty

Comment: There is an alternative way of doing it here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/195903/how-can-i-get-node-creation-date

Answer (score 0):

You can use {{ date }}.

Just leave editing of the altered on no content type enabled. Which case is changed will be displayed in this same variable